# How can I get the text to be at the bottom of an image?

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list of images that transition in the format below and I want each image to have a text overlay at the bottom of it. How should I style the paragraph div correctly to get the desired result? The text keeps appearing at the top.

```html
<li data-transition="fade">
  <img src="https://i217.photobucket.com/albums/cc312/mastersig/Avitars/For%20Me/C_D_A.png">
                
  <div style="bottom: 10px; left: 19px;font-size: 13px;">
    <p>Some text at the bottom</p>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use the correct HTML element - the `<figure>` element.**

Whilst all the other answers do provide a styling solution - the better approach is to use the correct html element - which in this case is the `HTML5 figure element`. This has the semantic structure of being a container to wrap around an image and a text element - the `figcaption` - which can either be the first child (ie - above the image) or the last child -ie - below the image.

Then you can style the figcaption to be on top of the image if desired (as noted in one of the  other solutions - position:relative on the parent figure element and position absolute on the figcaption).

```css
.list-item {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
figure {
  display: inline-block;  
  position: relative;
}

figcaption{
   background-color: wheat;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 4px;
   left: 0; 
   right:0
}
```

```html
<li class="list-item" data-transition="fade">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://i217.photobucket.com/albums/cc312/mastersig/Avitars/For%20Me/C_D_A.png">
    <figcaption>Some text at the bottom</figcaption>
  </figure>
   <figure>
    <img src="https://i217.photobucket.com/albums/cc312/mastersig/Avitars/For%20Me/C_D_A.png">
    <figcaption>Some text at the bottom</figcaption>
  </figure>
   <figure>
    <img src="https://i217.photobucket.com/albums/cc312/mastersig/Avitars/For%20Me/C_D_A.png">
    <figcaption>Some text at the bottom</figcaption>
  </figure>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Use correct style

When you use `bottom: 10px; left: 19px;` you need to add `position: absolute;` or relative.

The `<p>` tag have default margin so I write `margin: 0;` and thats all.

Preferable use class for style, and I add a little things.

```css
.item {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
   margin: 0;
   position: relative;
   top: -26px;
   background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<li class="item" data-transition="fade">
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="https://i217.photobucket.com/albums/cc312/mastersig/Avitars/For%20Me/C_D_A.png">
    <p class="text">Some text at the bottom</p>
  </div>
   <div class="wrap">
    <img src="https://i217.photobucket.com/albums/cc312/mastersig/Avitars/For%20Me/C_D_A.png">
    <p class="text">Some text at the bottom</p>
  </div>
   <div class="wrap">
    <img src="https://i217.photobucket.com/albums/cc312/mastersig/Avitars/For%20Me/C_D_A.png">
    <p class="text">Some text at the bottom</p>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: I actually don't want it under the image. I want it on top of the image at the bottom

Comment: I fix my answer further to the comments. Does the text may be longer? If yes you can use flex, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.container {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.text {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class=container>
            <p class="text">Some text</p>
            <img src="https://i217.photobucket.com/albums/cc312/mastersig/Avitars/For%20Me/C_D_A.png">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text">Some text</p>
            <img src="https://i217.photobucket.com/albums/cc312/mastersig/Avitars/For%20Me/C_D_A.png">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text">Some text</p>
            <img src="https://i217.photobucket.com/albums/cc312/mastersig/Avitars/For%20Me/C_D_A.png">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `position:relative` on the parent `li` and `position:absolute` on the text container

```css
.imgList li {
  /*Child items will be positioned relative to this*/
  position:relative; 
}

.imgList .title {
  /*Postition relative to parent li*/
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  left:19px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
}
```

```html
<ul class="imgList" >
<li data-transition="fade">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/300">
                
  <div class="title" >
    <p>Some text at the bottom</p>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can use this example:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;

}
div img {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  position: relative;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  background:red;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  
}
.main {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div>
  <img src="https://i217.photobucket.com/albums/cc312/mastersig/Avitars/For%20Me/C_D_A.png">
                

    <p>Some text at the bottom</p>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://i217.photobucket.com/albums/cc312/mastersig/Avitars/For%20Me/C_D_A.png">
                

    <p>Some text at the bottom</p>
</div>
</div>
```